# jQuery Get Multiple Checkbox Value each and Store to Database

Tags: php, jquery

I have multiple checkbox to get all favourites fruits.

HTML

```
List Favourite<br>

    <table border=1>
        <th rowspan=3>Name</th>
        <tr>
        <th colspan=3>Favourite Fruits</th>
        <tr>
        <th>Banana</th>
        <th>Apple</th>
        <th>Mangoes</th>

        <tr>

        <td>John<input type="hidden" id="U0001"/></td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Banana"/>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Apple"/>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Mangoes"/>
        </td>

        <tr>

        <td>Mark<input type="hidden" id="U0002"/></td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Banana"/>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Apple"/>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Mangoes"/>
        </td>

        <tr>

        <td colspan=4>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
        </td>
    </table>
```

The steps is:
1. There are 2 users, John and Mark
2. Then We tick the favourites fruits for each
3. After that click the submit button
4. Save it to database

Now the question is:
**How to get all the value of checkbox checked by each users base on his User ID(on input hidden) by btnSubmit click and store it to database?**

Example will save on table
Table

```
uid    | favourites_fruits
U0001  | Apple, Mangoes
U0002  | Banana, Apple
```

JS

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function()
{

});
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05eb11rx/)

Comment: How are you sending information to the database at the moment? Are you using a form? AJAX? Either way, please update your code to show this. Also, are you trying to get the values in jQuery or are you trying to get them in PHP?

Comment: Hi @ObsidianAge I'm using AJAX. on btnSubmit click

Comment: @ObsidianAge That's why I'm asking, because I didn't know how to do with ajax and send it to PHP. Please advice

Comment: Sure thing. I'm crafting an AJAX request to do this now :)

Comment: OK, waiting for your update :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract the values from the associated elements, and decide how you're going to store them. In this example, I've created two separate arrays: `johns_favourite_fruits` and `marks_favourite_fruits`. You check against the `.checked` attribute, and if it's true, you add the associated value to the array. This array then gets posted to the server in a JSON format.

This isn't necessarily the most elegant way of going about this, but it gets the job done:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
  // Collect the results
  var fruitsNodeList = document.getElementsByName("fruits[]");
  var johns_favourite_fruits = [];
  var marks_favourite_fruits = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < fruitsNodeList.length; i++) {
    if (i < 3) {
      if (fruitsNodeList[i].checked) {
        johns_favourite_fruits.push(fruitsNodeList[i].value);
      }
    } else {
      if (fruitsNodeList[i].checked) {
        marks_favourite_fruits.push(fruitsNodeList[i].value);
      }
    }
  }

  // Debug
  console.log(johns_favourite_fruits);
  console.log(marks_favourite_fruits);

  // Post the results
  $.post("update.php", // Replace this with your PHP script
    {
        johns_favourite_fruits: johns_favourite_fruits,
        marks_favourite_fruits: marks_favourite_fruits
    },
    function(data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
  );
});
```

Once you have submitted the values, you can extract them from `$_POST`, and insert them into the database from there:

```
$_POST['johns_favourite_fruits'];
$_POST['marks_favourite_fruits'];
```

How you insert them depends on whether you're using MySQL, MySQLi, or PDO. Naturally, you should definitely use parameterised queries!

I've created a JSFiddle showcasing the JavaScript [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/9qxpafub/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, just now tried your code but got error on alert, Data: <br/><bNotice</b>: Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\siixwebapps\update.php </b> on line <b>2</b><br/>

Comment: and how about if the checkbox is more than 2 users? So I need to make new var for new name?

Comment: Well you'd either need to do that, or create a loop that goes over each TD. To be honest, the HTML itself should **really** be re-written so that it's a proper form. You don't typically submit complicated posts like this with AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

I have made slight modification in HTML mockup to take advantage of selector.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    $('#result').html('');
    $('.users').each(function() {
      var uid = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#result').append('<h3>' + $(this).parent().text() + '\'s favourite fruit(s)</h3>');
      $('input[data-uid=' + uid + ']:checked').each(function() {
        $('#result').append('<div>'+ $(this).val() + '</div>');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
List Favourite<br>

<table border=1>
  <th rowspan=3>Name</th>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=3>Favourite Fruits</th>
    <tr>
      <th>Banana</th>
      <th>Apple</th>
      <th>Mangoes</th>

      <tr>

        <td>John<input type="hidden" class="users" id="U0001" /></td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" data-uid="U0001" name="fruits[]" value="Banana" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" data-uid="U0001" name="fruits[]" value="Apple" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" data-uid="U0001" name="fruits[]" value="Mangoes" />
        </td>

        <tr>

          <td>Mark<input type="hidden" id="U0002" class="users" /></td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Banana" data-uid="U0002" />
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Apple" data-uid="U0002" />
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="Mangoes" data-uid="U0002" />
          </td>

          <tr>

            <td colspan=4>
              <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />
            </td>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @jagdish.narkar, thanks for the answer, Question how to pass it to PHP using ajax?

Comment: Please advice Sir

Comment: Follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: how to divide for each value to ajax PHP (John and Mark)? You show me only the output, I need it to store to PHP too. Please help